# How do you add a drop down list on a page item on a Master Detail page for Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, dropdown

It looks like this

[image: Drop1]
[image: Drop2]

I've been working on a medical app and used MasterDetailPage to put all the navigation into one place. But it was too much so I figure to have it categorize into one of each. I thought of drop down menu on each page item. I've been searching the internet about implementing it but I couldn't figure it out.This is Xamarin on android and I wanted to make a drop down similar to the image above.

This is my code so far on C#

```
namespace MasterDetailPageNavigation
{
    public partial class MasterPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ListView ListView { get { return listView; } }

        public MasterPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex ("ffffff");
            var masterPageItems = new List<MasterPageItem> ();
            masterPageItems.Add (new MasterPageItem {
                Title = "DashBoard",
                TargetType = typeof(DashBoard)
            });
            masterPageItems.Add (new MasterPageItem {
                Title = "Schedules",
                TargetType = typeof(SchedulesCS)
            });

            masterPageItems.Add (new MasterPageItem {
                Title = "Master Data",
                TargetType = typeof(MasterDataCS)
            });

            masterPageItems.Add (new MasterPageItem {
                Title = "Audit Trail",
                TargetType = typeof(AuditTrailCS)
            });

            listView.ItemsSource = masterPageItems;
        }
    }
}
```

For the xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="MasterDetailPageNavigation.MasterPage"
             Padding="0,40,0,0"
             Icon="hamburger.png"
             Title="Medical">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ListView x:Name="listView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" SeparatorVisibility="None">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ImageCell Text="{Binding Title}" ImageSource="{Binding IconSource}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

How do you do it?